# Routed Events of TextBlock

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

How to fire RoutedEvents of TextBlock in ViewModel from code behind in wpf.
Kindly let me know, how I can bind routed events in wpf code behind. Thanks

Comment: Can you be little more specific? You questions seems ambigious. Are you trying to trigger routed events from ViewModel or you want to bind routed event to view model? Any peiece of code or even pseudo code will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I use this (you will need System.Windows.Interactivity in Silverlight, but I suspect it's similar in WPF):

```
xmlns:GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.SL4"   
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"


 <TextBlock Text="{Binding InputValue, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
                <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding InputValueGotFocusCommand}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBlock>
```

You can do this easy in Blend